# `gradlew run` can not find the main kotlin class even though using default directory structure

Tags: kotlin, gradle

My project's `gradle/kotlin` directory structure follows the default/recommended approach:

```
MYPROJ
      /src/main/kotlin
                       app/OnsetsWebapp.kt
```

Here is the *build.gradle.kts* : notice we specify `mainClassName = app.OnsetsWebapp` :

```
plugins {
  application
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71"
}

application {
  mainClassName = "app.OnsetsWebapp"
}

dependencies {
  compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
  compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25")
  compile("io.javalin:javalin:3.8.0")
  compile("org.json:json:20160810")
  compile("com.j2html:j2html:1.3.0")
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}
```

Let's build it: `./gradlew build`

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
8 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Now let's run it:

```
 $./gradlew run
```

This results in

```
> Task :run FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class app.OnsetsWebapp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.OnsetsWebapp

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

So why is the class `app.OnsetsWebapp` not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be:

application {
mainClassName = "app.OnsetsWebappKt"
}

If you look in the `build/classes/kotlin/main/app` folder, you should see two class files there: `OnsetsWebappKt` and `OnsetsWebapp`. You want to one that has the `Kt` suffix

Comment: Uncertain on  this: here is what I see there `$ll build/classes/kotlin/main/app/OnsetsWebappKt*
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  7727 Jul 27 16:58 build/classes/kotlin/main/app/OnsetsWebappKt.class` . Oh! it _does_ have a `Kt` suffix.  OK trying that..

Comment: dude you rock.   I did not realize the Kotlin compiler appends `Kt` to the class names